# How to store the dataframe from the output from group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

How to store the dataframe from the output from pandas group by as something like output 2 given below without displaying both category in the first column (i think it is the index).

The below code output is given in the output 1 but I need to create something like output 2

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['a_category', 'b_category' ]). size(). unstack ()
```

Output1:

```
df1:

b_category        no     yes
a_category
A1                10     15
A2                20     22
A3                11     16
A4                12     26
```

Output :

df1:

```
a_category        no     yes
A1                10     15
A2                20     22
A3                11     16
A4                12     26
```

Comment: I think need `df1 = (df.groupby(['a_category', 'b_category' ]). size(). unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Yes jezrael. Thanks for your answer.